# Is defining measures as functionals ever insufficiently general in practice?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Crossposting from Math Stack Exchange, as it has yet to receive any answers there; the original question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842440/is-defining-measures-as-functionals-ever-insufficiently-general-in-practice).

---

The way I learned measures was as set functions on a $\sigma$-algebra with certain properties. However, I'm aware of another viewpoint, used for example in Bourbaki's *Integration*, that defines measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces to be functionals on the space of compactly-supported continuous functions. This is obviously less general, but I suppose the argument is that most measures that arise in practice are Radon measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

The counterpoint that I keep seeing cited is that this is insufficient for probability theory. In *Real and Complex Analysis* (p. 35), Rudin mentions the Wiener measure as an example of a measure that doesn't fall into this framework. However, I have also seen some sources say that the needs of probability theory can be met by extending the theory to general Hausdorff spaces. I've heard this as Bourbaki's rationale for adding a 9th chapter to *Integration* about measures on Hausdorff spaces (see for instance p. 14 of [this review](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/11/11-169.pdf?)), and in the introduction to *Radon Measures on Arbitrary Topological Spaces and Cylindrical Measures*, Schwartz says

> The fundamental defect of the usual theory of Radon measures is that the spaces of functions which occur in the theory of probability are not locally compact.

> The present theory of Radon measures on arbitrary (for the most part) Hausdorff topological spaces combines all the advantages of both methods [i.e., in terms of sets and in terms of functionals]...

My question is: does extending the functional approach to Hausdorff spaces actually make it general enough for the needs of probability theory? If not, are there examples of probabilistic concepts that are less easy (or impossible) to describe from this viewpoint? (I would also be happy to hear about fields other than probability for which this viewpoint does not suffice, if they exist.)

Comment: My objection to the *measures as functionals* approach would not be insufficient generality but rather excessive and unnecessary abstraction (an unease not alleviated by your reference to Bourbaki).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first time I taught myself rigorous measure theory, I used the "linear functionals on $C(X)$" approach for compact Hausdorff spaces, so I got first-hand knowledge of where it doesn't work for probability.

Consider the simplest case of the strong law of large numbers:

> The sample average of a sequence of independent fair coin flips converges almost surely to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Which is to say, the following set has measure $1$ under the independent product measure of Bernoulli trials with equal probability for $0$ and $1$:
$$
M = \left\{ (x_n)_n \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} \,\left\lvert\, \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \frac{1}{2} \right. \right\}
$$
(since this sometimes causes confusion, consider $2 = \{0,1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to interpret the above sum)

Using the linear functionals on $C(X)$ approach, one can only take the measure of a set $S$ whose indicator function $\chi_S$ is continuous, *i.e.* a clopen set. A clopen set in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ can only restrict the value of a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ at finitely many coordinates $i_1, \ldots, i_k \in \mathbb{N}$. One can therefore define a sequence $(y_n)_n$ satisfying these conditions at $i_1,\ldots,i_k$ and alternating back and forth between $0$ and $1$ for all $i > i_k$, making the sample average converge to $\frac{1}{2}$, and thereby showing that $M$ nontrivially intersects every clopen set, and is therefore a dense set with empty interior, so we can't express its measure. So the strong law of large numbers and related theorems such as the pointwise ergodic theorem are not doable. This also shows the inadequacy of measure theory based on [valuations on open sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(measure_theory)) or lower semicontinuous functions for this application.

Here are some other points against the Bourbaki approach:

1. Locally compact Hausdorff spaces are not closed under infinite products. In fact, a product of locally compact Hausdorff spaces is locally compact iff all but finitely many of the factors is compact. So the spaces of sequences $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are not locally compact. However, for probability theory this can be resolved using linear functionals on $C_b(X)$ (the space of bounded continuous functions) equipped with a certain topology (the 'strict topology', the finest locally convex topology $\mathcal{T}$ that agrees with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $X$ when restricted to norm-bounded subsets of $C_b(X)$). This also takes care of Wiener measure, white noise, and the measures on distributions used in bosonic quantum field theory (and moreover, 'measures' in fermionic quantum field theory must be viewed as functionals (on anticommuting algebras), because we don't have 'fermionic sets').
2. All uncountable Polish spaces are measurably isomorphic to each other and to $[0,1]$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. If you have a purely topological measure theory, you can't take advantage of this fact to reduce a measure-theoretic question on one space to a question that's easier to solve on one of these spaces using the other structures they have available.

---

I still advocate using the linear functional approach it when it works. I think at the time Bourbaki wrote the book, a lot of people were unduly resistant to using linear functionals to define measures, and it affords a lot of simplifications under certain circumstances (distribution theory, Grothendieck's work on inequalities and integral operators, C*-algebras, Haar measure - not coincidentally, areas important to Dieudonné, Schwartz and Weil, and the application to probability monads was important for my own work).

Another useful, if neglected, point of view is finitely-additive measures on the clopen sets of a Stone space, as these faithfully represent Baire measures and Radon Borel measures on that space just as well as linear functionals on the continuous functions. The infinite probability spaces one first encounters, *e.g.* $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ are Stone spaces. But this isn't good enough if you need *e.g.* the central limit theorem, which depends on the topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

I advocate against fixing a single definition as *the* definition, to be used at all times, forsaking all others, because different applications suggest the use of different definitions, overlapping but not quite always equivalent, for different purposes.

Comment: Using the linear functionals on $C(X)$ approach allows one to take the measure of *any* Borel set not just those sets $S$ whose indicator function $\chi_S$ is continuous.  For convenience say $X$ is compact, then the weak*-continuous extension of $\phi:C(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to $C(X)^{**}$ shows how to extend the measure to bounded Borel functions. Similar things work out in the non-compact case, Gert Pedersen's Analysis Now has the details worked out

Comment: @CalebEckhardt Pedersen doesn't work with $C(X)^{**}$ in *Analysis Now*. He defines outer and inner integrals on $\mathbb{R}^X$ and takes measurable functions to be the set of functions to be where they agree (the function version of Caratheodory's definition of measurable set), just like Bourbaki does. He is not as ideological as Bourbaki, so introduces $\sigma$-algebras and measures soon after.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt I could have made my answer longer by saying that I consider "monotone $\sigma$-complete subalgebras of $\mathbb{R}^X$" and "$\sigma$-complete Boolean subalgebras of $\mathcal{P}(X)$" to both be measure theory, as the proofs for the former tend to be translations of those for the latter, which were discovered first. You never regain the advantages that the "functionals on C(X)" approach has when it can be used to avoid measure theory entirely, which to me is the entire point of it.

Comment: Historically, Baire started with functions, and couldn't prove that there were functions properly of Baire class higher than 2. Lebesgue provided the first proof that there were functions of arbitrarily large (countable ordinal) Baire class by turning the problem from functions into sets (and Borel classes) and using a diagonal argument. In my example above of the law of large numbers, it is naturally formulated in terms of a set.

Comment: The reason you thought of Pedersen is probably that he invented definitions of lower semicontinuous, Baire and Borel functions in the noncommutative case, as subsets of $A^{**}$ for $A$ a C$^*$-algebra, as have come up before e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/192052). Unfortunately that theory is intrinsically more difficult than the commutative case.